# Shopware 5.5 Frontend Template changes wont load

Tags: javascript, symfony, shopware

so i updated to SW 5.5 and for some reason one of my own Plugins wont work anymore.
JS Files are still imported via Plugin BUT the plugin should add some Test  etc. to the frontend, but these things wont load anymore and i´m honestly dont know why.

here is the code for the files footer.tpl and index.tpl which should extends the original files, it worked before...but not anymore.

footer.tpl

```html
{extends file="parent:frontend/index/footer.tpl"}

{block name='frontend_index_footer_menu'}
    {$smarty.block.parent}
    <div id="example">
       Hello World!
    </div>
{/block}
```

index.tpl

```html
{extends file="parent:frontend/index/index.tpl"}

{block name='frontend_index_header_javascript_jquery_lib' append}
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

            var exampleJSvars =
                 {
                    height:"{$configHeight";
                };
    </script>

{/block}
```

If i forget something or you need more information, let me know

Answer (score 0):

**First:**

Why did you include jQuery in the bottom? jQuery is already loaded by Shopware, you don't have to include it twice.

**Second:**
Don't use `append` or `prepend`, use always `$smarty.block.parent` to extend a `{block}`.

**Third:**
In your code example, you forgot the closing Curly bracket. So the code would be:

```
{extends file="parent:frontend/index/index.tpl"}

{block name='frontend_index_header_javascript_jquery_lib'}
   {$smarty.block.parent}
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var exampleJSvars =
                 {
                    height:"{$configHeight}";
                };
    </script>

{/block}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer: first: i needed another jquery version so my script would work, dont know why exactly but as i did this, my script worked, on SW 5.3 now it wont even show up on the frontend as stated.   i will try your other suggestions but i dont think that this is it since the <div> and <script> elements wont even show up

Comment: Just curious - If you make a console.log('bla') in your bottom script, is this output visible in your console?
But to include two jQuery versions might not be the best solution. Shopware 5.5 is using jQuery 3.3.1 so you might think to update your plugin.

Comment: i tested it with console.log('test') etc. wont show up so footer.tpl and index.tpl are definitely not added to the frontend for some reason. - yes i know and as soon as my main problem is solved i will get into that, but right now thats not the main issue

Comment: Is your theme active? Did you cleared the cache? Are you using the dev config.php to avoid the caching?

Comment: But if the code isn't even showed up in the sourcecode, this sounds like a caching issue.

Comment: yea i know, but it isnt, so thats why i´m so confused because it worked before, hmm

Comment: found the issue, it was a syntax error within my plugin script that i missed.

Answer (score 0):

so this is fixed. but i´m pretty sure i have a mistake within my variables, because they wont show up in the frontend.

```html
    public function extendsFrontend(Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
    {
        /** @var \Enlight_Controller_Action $controller */
        $controller = $args->get('subject');
        $view = $controller->View();

        $view->addTemplateDir($this->pluginPath . '/Resources/views');

        $shop = Shopware()->Shop();
        $this->config = Shopware()->Container()->get('shopware.plugin.cached_config_reader')->getByPluginName($this->pluginName, $shop);

        $config = array(
            'height' => $this->config['height']
        );

        $view->assign($this->pluginName, $config);
    }
```

That is my function so i could use {$height} so display this option on the frontend but this doesnt work anymore either and honestly...i dont see the issue with my script